# how to access each value of csv file using iterrow and save in variables in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file and I am reading this file in python using pandas. I want to read each row of file and store each value of that row in a variable using a loop. How should I do this.

```html
Station MAC, First time seen, Last time seen, Power, # packets, BSSID, Probed ESSIDs
macaddrees, 2018-06-22 11:23:45, 2018-06-22 11:23:45, -78,        8, 52:62:90:00:03:01,
macaddress, 2018-06-22 11:23:46, 2018-06-22 11:24:05, -73,        4, 14:30:04:BB:19:A2,
macaddress, 2018-06-22 11:23:52, 2018-06-22 11:24:12, -73,        5, (not associated) ,
macaddress, 2018-06-22 11:23:43, 2018-06-22 11:24:12, -71,        9, not assocaited,
macadress, 2018-06-22 11:23:52, 2018-06-22 11:23:52, -70,        2, (not associated) ,
macaddress, 2018-06-22 11:23:48, 2018-06-22 11:24:01, -69,       11, NAN,
macaddress, 2018-06-22 11:23:46, 2018-06-22 11:24:12, -65,       15, NAN,
macaddress, 2018-06-22 11:24:12, 2018-06-22 11:24:12, -62,        2, (not associated) ,
macaddress, 2018-06-22 11:24:01, 2018-06-22 11:24:12, -54,        2, NAN,
macaddress, 2018-06-22 11:23:49, 2018-06-22 11:24:12, -48,       97, NAN,
macaddress, 2018-06-22 11:23:43, 2018-06-22 11:24:12, -35,       54, NAN,UET Smart University
macaddress, 2018-06-22 11:23:47, 2018-06-22 11:24:03, -23,      108, NAN,
macaddress, 2018-06-22 11:23:49, 2018-06-22 11:23:49,  -1,        9, NAN,
```

what i have tried is

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
Station_Mac=(row["Station MAC"])
First_Time_seen=(row["First time seen"])
print(Station_Mac)
```

I want to get variables Station MAC, BSSID etc to pass them to payload function to send data to database

```html
import requests

url = "http://localhost/api/customers_data/create.php"

payload = "{\n \"Station_MAC\": \"56:12:34:345\",\n \n \"First_time_seen\": \"12:45:66:32\",\n \n \"Last_time_seen\": \"-89\",\n \n \"Power\": \"-48\",\n \n \"Packets\": \"12\",\n \n \"BSSID\": \"65:08:08:98\",\n \n \"Probed_ESSIDs\": \"93\"\n}"
headers = {
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
    'Postman-Token': "ca64cf56-19e8-4e6c-85a7-1741355ced79"
    }

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I want to save this file in database using web api

Comment: I would not recommend this. Does the API not support sending an entire table at once? Or accepting an entire row?

Comment: No api only insertion by row values

Comment: what's the format you need for each row, like a `dict`?

Comment: I want each value of each row and want to save each value in a variable

Comment: What do you want to do with these variables once they have the values from the dataframe?

Comment: I want to pass those variables in payload function to save in database

Comment: see my uploaded code

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to verify versions

`np.__version__ '1.14.3'`

`pd.__version__ '0.24.1'`

```
all_vars = np.array(df).flatten().tolist()
```

Comment: I am getting every row record separately but I also want to save each value in variable returned by this code.

Comment: are you expecting the function to return M * N variables at the end of the loop?

Comment: what It will do for me?